# Checking registrations against a CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, registration

I am new to MySQL and PHP(as you can probably tell) and I was wondering if anybody knew an easy way to import a CSV file into a MySQL table.

> "There are any number of ways to input
>   csv into mysql depending in what kind
>   of access you have, if you can use the
>   mysql client directly there is a
>   command to load delimited data,
>   something like that could basically be
>   entered directly in cron and keep
>   itself up to date. Otherwise there are
>   various php scripts to do that sort of
>   thing."

That is something a friend told me to do, is that the easiest/best way to do it? If it is would someone mind explaining it to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the step-by-step to extend Mrgreen's answer :

1. install phpmyadmin
2. choose your database
3. choose your table
4. 'Import'
5. select your CSV file
6. set 'Format of imported file' to CSV

Answer (score 1):

Use the "load data infile"  command. By deafulat it will treat incoming files as csv, although you can define a custom file type to import. Documentation for load data infile is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

FTA, in its simplest form the command looks just like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

That assumes the columns in the data file and in your text file line up. 
The rest of the documentation explains how to get non-lined up fields imported, and also how to deal with windows vs unix style line terminations.

Comment: Is it possible to put a link inplace of 'data.txt' in your above example?

Comment: no, you need to download your datafile first. Use wget or curl if you are on a linux system.

Comment: With php you could also upload the file, and then use the move_uploaded_file() to place the file where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting to MySQL and PHP a nice way I started was with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html).

> XAMPP is an easy to install Apache
>   distribution containing MySQL, PHP and
>   Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to
>   install and to use - just download,
>   extract and start.

The package includes phpMyAdmin which makes it really easy to upload CSVs and manage your MySQL database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a hosting service and I doubt they would allow me to install it but I will try it anyway :)